# Book about the new president of the solar system having amnesia

Tags: story-identification

I would like to re-read a book I recall from high school, likely written in the 1970s or early 80s based on the prose. It is essentially a reverse detective story, the clues are there all along but only become clear to the protagonist over time.

It involves a man who wakes up with amnesia and does not recognize himself. He continues to wake up in strange places, especially a private medical clinic in Earth orbit. People keep confusing him with the former president, although he is clearly not that person. He keeps having dreams about something along the lines of "the fish eye lens, [something else], the blob that ate the stars!"

Over time it is revealed that he has the capability to teleport, which is why he keeps waking up in different places. Through a series of unintended jumps he keeps revisiting the same places that he realizes are somehow interconnected. He also continues to have the dream, but each time it becomes more and more clear what he is seeing. He is helped by a young woman who had grown up on Mars and recognizes his dream as the view through one of the observation domes on the surface.

> By the end we learn he is the recently elected president of the solar system. No one recognizes him as such because the dictatorial former president had their bodies switched at the clinic so he could continue ruling. He returns to the clinic in Earth orbit and has the procedure reversed. The dome was not on Mars but one of Jupiter's moons, where as a child he was scared when he first saw Jupiter filing the entire sky and now has recurring nightmares.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gah, I simply should have googled the one passage I recalled. That brought it up immediately:

https://books.google.ca/books?id=hLbyLUxFYl4C&pg=PA3

The book is "The Mindblocked Man" by Jeff Sutton.

It seems I remembered it pretty accurately with the exception of the bit about the apartment. Reviews are mixed, which I would agree with, but I did *really* enjoy the part about the recurring dream and what it turned out to be.

Comment: Added! And thanks for the note, I should have done that in the first place.